# Update query strings onChange - reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, query-string

I have a url with query strings which looks like this

```
http://localhost:3000/collection?page=1&limit=15&filter=%27%27&filterInitDate=2019/11/11&filterEndDate=2019/11/11
```

I want to update just the `filterInitDate` when i select a date from my date input. I know i can update the url simply by using `this.props.history.push` but how can i just change/update the `filterInitDate` when i change the date input

ideally something like this

```
history.push(`/collection?filterInitDate=${startDate}`)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) and [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) classes for that, here is an example:

```js
const urlStr = 'http://localhost:3000/collection?page=1&limit=15&filter=%27%27&filterInitDate=2019/11/11&filterEndDate=2019/11/11';
const url = new URL(urlStr);
url.searchParams.set("filterInitDate", "2019/11/12");

console.log(url.toString());
```

And an example specific to react router will look like this:

```
const query = new URLSearchParams(history.location.search);
query.set("filterInitDate", startDate);
history.replace({
  search: query.toString()
});
```